# in React, is <input value={func(item.foo)} a performance problem?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-hook-form

I may be mixing best practices between React and Angular...

in React, does this incur performance penalties or memory issues?

I know it's not good practice.  In Angular it would be the kiss of death.

```
//assume all the standard boilerplate around this :) 

...
//using redux, react-hook-form 

const fn=(x)=> `${x}-modifying the input value`;

...

return (
  <input value={fn(item.foo)} />   
  //or 
  <input value={()=>fn(item.foo)} />
)
```

Comment: This would not be a big deal in React.js. As long as the function itself is simple, which in this case is, I wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: If `item.foo` doesn't change a lot and `fn` is more expensive, it may be better to use `useMemo`.

Comment: irfanullah if you reply I can mark it as answer

Answer (score 0):

as irfanullah jan stated, it's not a performance problem in and of itself.

I do feel it should be avoided when possible, especially when working with groups supporting both Angular and React.